# TypeScript: Idiomatic way to do a switch-case on Enum to set a variable

Tags: javascript, typescript

Example problem: I have an Enum variable `Difficulty`. In a function, I want to set the config `DifficultyConfig` depending on the value of `Difficulty`. Here's an inelegant way that I can think of:

```
export interface DifficultyConfig {
    healthModifier: number,
    deathIsPermanent: boolean,
}

export interface AppProps {
    difficultyConfig: DifficultyConfig
}

export const NormalDifficultyConfig: DifficultyConfig = {
    enemyHealthModifier: 1,
    deathIsPermanent: false,
}

export const HigherDifficultyConfig: DifficultyConfig = {
    enemyHealthModifier: 1.3,
    deathIsPermanent: true, 
}

export enum Difficulty {
    NORMAL = 'Normal',
    HARD = 'Hard',
    ADVANCED = 'Advanced',
}

function createApp(difficulty: Difficulty) {
    let difficultyConfig: DifficultyConfig;
    
    switch(difficulty) {
        case Difficulty.NORMAL: 
            difficultyConfig = NormalDifficultyConfig;
            break;
        // Both HARD and ADVANCED get HigherDifficultyConfig
        case Difficulty.HARD:
            difficultyConfig = HigherDifficultyConfig;
            break;
        case Difficulty.ADVANCED: 
            difficultyConfig = HigherDifficultyConfig;
            break;
        default: 
            difficultyConfig = NormalDifficultyConfig;
            break;
    }
    
    return new App({
        difficultyConfig
    });
}
```

I'm not fond of the Switch case syntax for something so simple. My ideal would be something like this in Scala:

```
val difficultyConfig = difficulty match {
    case Difficulty.NORMAL => NormalDifficultyConfig
    case Difficulty.HARD | Difficulty.ADVANCED => HigherDifficultyConfig
    case _ => NormalDifficultyConfig
}
```

Is there an equivalent for this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there's a difference in *logic*, a `switch` or an `if`/`else if`/`else` (*slightly* less verbose) is probably the way to go (more on this below though). If it's purely data as in your example, then you could use a difficulty-to-config mapping object:

```typescript
const difficultyConfigs = {
    [Difficulty.NORMAL]: NormalDifficultyConfig,
    [Difficulty.HARD]: HigherDifficultyConfig,
    [Difficulty.ADVANCED]: HigherDifficultyConfig,
} as const;
```

You might even declare that as `Record<Difficult, DifficultyConfig>` like this, as [caTS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18244921/cats) points out in the comments:

```typescript
const difficultyConfigs: Record<Difficult, DifficultyConfig> = {
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [Difficulty.NORMAL]: NormalDifficultyConfig,
    [Difficulty.HARD]: HigherDifficultyConfig,
    [Difficulty.ADVANCED]: HigherDifficultyConfig,
} as const;
```

More on that in a minute, but either way, then the function is just:

```typescript
function createApp(difficulty: Difficulty) {
    let difficultyConfig = difficultyConfigs[difficulty];
    
    return new App({
        difficultyConfig
    });
}
```

Playground links: [Without `Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgEQXXQWwFcAbGATwGEIkSBzOAbwFgAoOHuAC2CYqfALIQAJkQRoAXHAByZALYAjNABouvOOMEw+ASQDOABTRLMSYCjkqIECoKSbOAXy5dQkWIhRosuHAAgmBgJlAQYEZsWrySxKSUNPSMCExyhAnkVHQMzFzunJ7g0PDYDEbw8tAWFJkk2cl5aRlEDUm5qSwAvDHcvAJC+mLx0lByAIwu2rqY+sZmUBZWNnBYFEbALoXF3mUV8AASaQJQ9Yk5KcytWR1XaXC9HP08g8IjUrJwEwB0AMzTOJ6QymcyWawwOQwKBkLZwAoeTheUpwazKAhtC40PraeQAeQASiIggAZR5wADk1SWQgpgJ4hyCBPw5Iph0wUHEdNiPCC+AAakF5LQAKIs3oUoLiABullwXO2iPKSEqOkxjU6zGiTx5cAA2ucNT98UTSQBdOTU2qGu7NJj0-U2nI-RnMi1wY5MU5OppdB0G9UdH58wXCsXuz3ewOXO3bOCYaLKyoAbkR6DISGwMAQDDg2CgemAITAAAp4u0cjcKzQAJQ43iOeDlrGah69Zsa+5MIx6jsdM2pl7wocFmBkKBIOBWADuwVCJee2hm0d9+SHrhrg9cQA) | [With `Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Kz1ztmeuIA) *(I also updated a couple of seeming typos/editing errors in the question's code.)*

This also has the advantage that if you add a `Difficulty` but forget to include one in `difficultyConfigs`, you get a handy *compile*-time error when you use it. I've simulated such an error [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-YHYzQfnzBcKxRGozHg3Guts4JhoibKgBuRHoMhIbAwBAMODYKB6YAhMAACni7RyNw7NAAlDjeI54O2sVaHr1h5b7kwjPaJx13cW4AB6JdwEVQCJQfhoPAFnTAIwIBviO12hswMhQJBwKwAd2CoRbz20M2zTS6dtcPdLbiAA) by adding a `MEDIUM` difficulty but "forgetting" to update the function.

But better yet, if we include the type `Record<Difficulty, DifficultyConfig>` type as [caTS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18244921/cats) suggested and `difficultyConfigs` doesn't have an entry for every `Difficulty` value, you get an even earlier compile-time error, [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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).

---

Even for logic, if you like you can use the same sort of concept to create a dispatch object:

```typescript
const difficultyConfigs: Record<Difficulty, () => DifficultyConfig> = {
    [Difficulty.NORMAL]: () => { /*...build and return NORMAL config...*/ },
    [Difficulty.HARD]: () => { /*...build and return HARD config...*/ },,
    [Difficulty.ADVANCED]: () => { /*...build and return ADVANCED config...*/ },,
} as const;
// ...
const difficultyConfig = difficultyConfigs[difficulty]();
```

Comment: Use a record so it'll warn you if you miss a member, but I suppose it would still warn you when you try to index into it anyways :)

Comment: Well yeah if you forget to add a member in `difficultyConfigs` you'll get an error but if you use a record then it'll warn you at the definition instead. Not really much of a difference.

Comment: @caTS - Neat! I'll add that, thanks!